# Gogs turning off CRON jobs

Tags: git, gogs

In the Gogs cheat sheet for app.ini there's this parameter:

```
ENABLED: Enable this to allow users upload attachments.
```

And this:

```
ENABLED: Enable this to run cron tasks periodically.
```

So is there a conflict here?  I've noticed that above the configuration settings there is a bracket header like this:

```
[picture]                     
DISABLE_GRAVATAR = false
```

So I'm assuming that perhaps:

```
[cron] 
ENABLED
```

Might work - but I'm just guessing ... Anyone have any experience with this?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app.ini` keys are unique per given scope / context.  So for cron jobs the scope is `cron` and it is declared like this for example:

```
[cron]
ENABLED = false
```